# typeof jQuery.data() buggy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tracking a mysterious problem in my code. This "bug" happens within an `event handler` that was bound via jQuery's `.delegate()`:

```
my.$table_body.delegate('.wf-dropdown', 'change', function(e){
    parent_row_element = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0];

    if( typeof $.data(parent_row_element, 'changed') == 'undefined' )
        $.data(parent_row_element, 'changed', {});

    $.data(parent_row_element, 'changed').wf_id = e.target.value;
    // .. more code
});
```

You don't need to know where some of those variables are defined and what they are for, the mysterious thing happens on the check for the `undefined` value.
I obviously check if there already is an object attached to the `parent_row_element` and if not, create it. It seems like `typeof $.data(anything)` fails in a way I cannot describe really. If a debugger like Firebug is attached, it evaluates to `undefined` correctly and everything works fine, without debugger, the assignment to `.wf_id` always throws because the object is undefined, because it was not created.

It works perfectly if I use this statement:

```
if(!$.data(parent_row_element, 'changed') )
    $.data(parent_row_element, 'changed', {});
```

That's why I guess that this is a bug. Or do I overlook something here ?

I could reproduce this behavior:

**throws an error on click, typeof is used**
http://www.jsfiddle.net/5cEVf/

**works fine, no typeof**
http://www.jsfiddle.net/5cEVf/3/

Comment: You're in scary territory here with that use of `==` instead of `===`. (oh wait it's on the "typeof" result - never mind)

Comment: @Pointy: I don't think so ? `==` shouldn't be a problem at all, anyways both `==` and `===` evaluate to `true` in debug mode.

Comment: why don't you `alert` the result of `typeof` so you can see what happens without using a debugger.

Comment: @Gaby: I console.log'ed it. The `if` statement does NOT go into the body and therefor no object is created.

Comment: Well the code for the "$.data" function isn't very complicated. It's not clear what it could possibly be doing that'd cause "typeof" on its result to behave incorrectly.

Comment: Is it possible that the "changed" attribute is sometimes somehow being set to `null` by something?

Comment: @patrick dw is correct - it's a 1.4.2 thing. The older jQuery version is returning an explicit `null` to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade past 1.4.2 and it is fixed.

If you alert the result of the `typeof`, you get `object` in 1.4.2.

Comment: Looks like a `return null;` in 1.4.2 is now just `return;`

Comment: Looks like that. I was so confused because if you evaluate the whole `typeof` statement during a FireBug debug session it returns really `undefined`.

Comment: btw.. I can't upgrade to 1.4.4 for that specific project. The new css handling screws up the code at serveral places.

Comment: @jAndy - Logging in Firefox gives me `object` when I do `console.log(typeof $.data(parent_row_element, 'changed'));` Strange that it would give you `undefined`.

Comment: @patrick: Might be. I was using the a breakpoint or `debugger` statement. Copy the expression into 'monitoring' on the right side and let it evaluate...

Comment: @jAndy - Oh, I see. I just closed FF, but I can take your word for it. I misunderstood how you were testing it.

Comment: The exact change is https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/9e06903a99caf5619d0db858ed3d24f0e6ee15db from issue http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6166

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the the value is set to null and null is an object.

So the `typeof` returns `'object'` which makes your `if` fail and since the object is null it also fails the assignment of a new property.

Comment: I don't think the value is actually `null` - it really does look like a jQuery bug that's been fixed in 1.4.3 or 1.4.4.  The old code would *explicitly* return `null` when no "data" stuff was present for a particular element.

Comment: @Pointy, yes i meant the return from the `.data()` would be null and `typeof null == 'object'`.

Comment: I already pointed that out in a comment to patrick dw's answer. Firebug debbug monitoring evalutes the expression to `undefined` anyway.